# Bokeh: linking a line plot and a scatter plot

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a line plot and a scatter plot that are conceptually linked by sample IDs, i.e. each dot on the 2D scatter plot corresponds to a line on the line plot.

While I have done linked plotting before using scatter plots, I have not seen examples of this for the situation above - where I select dots and thus selectively view lines.

Is it possible to link dots on a scatter plot to a line on a line plot? If so, is there an example implementation available online?

Searching the web for [bokeh link line and scatter plot](https://www.google.com/search?q=bokeh+link+line+and+scatter+plot&oq=bokeh+link+line+and+scatter+plot&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j69i61.3506j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) yields no examples online, as of 14 August 2018.

Comment: This is certainly possible, in a variety of ways in fact, which is why the question as posed is too broad.

Comment: Thanks @bigreddot, for the feedback! Is there an example of this somewhere in the docs? I have not been able to find anything under https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/linking.html. I will update the question to be more specific.

Comment: Standalone Bokeh output? Bokeh server application? You need to be *much more specific* In general SO is intended for questions where you can provide some actual code for what you have tried, seeking help finishing, fixing, or improving it.

Comment: I was thinking of Bokeh output in the Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Apologies, @bigreddot, if I've been asking this in a manner that's causing you frustration. That said, I genuinely don't know where to start for this, thus I have no code. I can do linked brushing in both standalone Bokeh outputs and server applications for a scatter plot, but I'm missing something in my mental model that's stopping me from asking in a better fashion. 

If this is not the right place to ask this, then where should I go? Issues tracker doesn't sound right to me; Google Groups then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As things turn out, I was able to make this happen by using HoloViews rather than Bokeh. The relevant example for making this work comes from the `Selection1d tap` stream.

http://holoviews.org/reference/streams/bokeh/Selection1D_tap.html#selection1d-tap

I will do an annotated version of the example below.

First, we begin with imports. (Note: all of this assumes work is being done in the Jupyter notebook.)

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews.streams import Selection1D
from scipy import stats
hv.extension('bokeh')
```

First off, we set some styling options for the charts. In my experience, I usually build the chart before styling it, though.

```
%%opts Scatter [color_index=2 tools=['tap', 'hover'] width=600] {+framewise} (marker='triangle' cmap='Set1' size=10)
%%opts Overlay [toolbar='above' legend_position='right'] Curve (line_color='black') {+framewise}
```

This function below generates data.

```
def gen_samples(N, corr=0.8):
    xx = np.array([-0.51, 51.2])
    yy = np.array([0.33, 51.6])
    means = [xx.mean(), yy.mean()]  
    stds = [xx.std() / 3, yy.std() / 3]
    covs = [[stds[0]**2          , stds[0]*stds[1]*corr], 
            [stds[0]*stds[1]*corr,           stds[1]**2]] 

    return np.random.multivariate_normal(means, covs, N)

data = [('Week %d' % (i%10), np.random.rand(), chr(65+np.random.randint(5)), i) for i in range(100)]
sample_data = hv.NdOverlay({i: hv.Points(gen_samples(np.random.randint(1000, 5000), r2))
                            for _, r2, _, i in data})
```

The real magic begins here. First off, we set up a scatterplot using the `hv.Scatter` object.

```
points = hv.Scatter(data, ['Date', 'r2'], ['block', 'id']).redim.range(r2=(0., 1))
```

Then, we create a `Selection1D` stream. It pulls in points from the `points` object.

```
stream = Selection1D(source=points)
```

We then create a function to display the regression plot on the right. There's an empty plot that is the "default", and then there's a callback that `hv.DynamicMap` calls on.

```
empty = (hv.Points(np.random.rand(0, 2)) * hv.Curve(np.random.rand(0, 2))).relabel('No selection')

def regression(index):
    if not index:
        return empty
    scatter = sample_data[index[0]]
    xs, ys = scatter['x'], scatter['y']
    slope, intercep, rval, pval, std = stats.linregress(xs, ys)
    xs = np.linspace(*scatter.range(0)+(2,))
    reg = slope*xs+intercep
    return (scatter * hv.Curve((xs, reg))).relabel('r2: %.3f' % slope)
```

Now, we create the DynamicMap which dynamically loads the regression curve data.

```
reg = hv.DynamicMap(regression, kdims=[], streams=[stream])

# Ignoring annotation for average - it is not relevant here.    
average = hv.Curve(points, 'Date', 'r2').aggregate(function=np.mean)
```

Finally, we display the plots.

```
points * average + reg
```

The most important thing I learned from building this is that the indices for the points have to be lined up with the indices for the regression curves.

I hope this helps others building awesome viz using HoloViews!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a little late - but maybe this snippet of code will help?

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import Circle,MultiLine

def play():
    x = np.linspace(0,10,100)
    y = np.random.rand(100)
    xs = np.random.rand(100,3)
    ys = np.random.normal(size=(100,3))
    xp = [list(xi) for xi in xs] # Because Multi-List does not like numpy arrays
    yp = [list(yi) for yi in ys]
    output_file('play.html')
    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x,y=y,xp=xp,yp=yp))
    TOOLS = 'box_select'
    left = figure(tools=TOOLS,plot_width=700,plot_height=700)
    c1 = left.circle('x','y',source=source)
    c1.nonselection_glyph = Circle(fill_color='gray',fill_alpha=0.4,
                                   line_color=None)
    c1.selection_glyph = Circle(fill_color='orange',line_color=None)
    right = figure(tools=TOOLS,plot_width=700,plot_height=700)
    c2 = right.multi_line(xs='xp',ys='yp',source=source)
    c2.nonselection_glyph = MultiLine(line_color='gray',line_alpha=0.2)
    c2.selection_glyph = MultiLine(line_color='orange')
    p = gridplot([[left, right]])
    show(p)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, @Samir! It is a good attempt. I have, however, found that the use of HoloViews makes this much easier and less verbose to build. I hope you'll give it a shot too!